# Unity Character sliding on tilemap, but only at certain velocity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I am currently making my first "bigger" 2D game in unity and I used a `Tilemap` for creating a tutorial level.

The enemy moves toward the player direction, if the distance between them is less than `m_attackRange` the enemy throws a melee attack.

Usually the enemy stops moving, throws the attack, takes a short break and if its still in range attacks again otherwise tries to  move towards the player again.

The problem is that the enemy starts sliding and pushing the player away while continuously attacking, but that only happens if the enemy has reached a certain velocity.

This is the moving and attacking part in the `Update()` method of my enemy script.

```cs
// Move towards the target if it is within range
if (m_target != null && Vector2.Distance(transform.position, m_target.transform.position) <= m_targetRange && !m_isAttacking)
{
   transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, m_target.transform.position, m_speed * Time.deltaTime);
}

// Check if the target is within range and if enough time has passed since the last attack
if (m_target != null && Vector2.Distance(transform.position, m_target.transform.position) <= m_attackRange && m_timeSinceLastAttack >= m_attackRate && !m_isAttacking)
{
    m_isAttacking = true;
    m_timeSinceLastAttack = 0;
}
if (m_animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime > 1)
{
    m_isAttacking = false;
}
m_timeSinceLastAttack += Time.deltaTime;
```

I tried zeroing out the velocity of the enemy object before attacking without any success, it just keeps moving.

I put Material on the `Tilemap Collider 2D` component with friction.

The only "workaround" is if I jump above the attack to slow the enemy down after attacking but as soon as I run away and the enemy gets some speed, it starts sliding and pushing again.

I would highly appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this and I try to give more information as fast as possible if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the condition for the transform command (aka the moving part) to only be activated when the player is in targetRange AND not in attackRange. Additionally i had to set the "isAttacking" flag to false at a later point to properly match the attacking animation and attacking time

So my enemy was not "sliding" because the transform command was active when it should not have been and that is also why the velocity zeroing didnt work, cause it always has been zero

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your script to avoid repetitions, hence getting a bit more performance, after all computations on the `Update()` method run every frame.

You were checking twice for `m_target` and for `m_isAttacking` while doesnt seem necessary. You where also calculating the distance twice.

As the bot mentions in a comment, your own answer its unclear, hope you did manage to understand your issue and fix your script but with this version of the script bellow, I fixed the *sliding* issue by just rearranging the order of your logic.

```cs
//Check if there is a target
if (m_target != null)
{
    //Check is attacking
    if (!m_isAttacking)
    {
        //Calculate distance
        var distance = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, m_target.transform.position);
        // Check if target is within range
        if (distance <= m_targetRange)
        {
            //Check if target is within attack range
            if(distance <= m_attackRange && m_timeSinceLastAttack >= m_attackRate)
            {
                //Attack
                m_isAttacking = true;
                m_timeSinceLastAttack = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                //Move
                transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, m_target.transform.position, m_speed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //If its attacking wait for animation to end
        if (m_animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime > 1)
        {
            m_isAttacking = false;
        }
    }
    //Accumulate time since last attack
    m_timeSinceLastAttack += Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Consider wrapping this logic in methods, for instance the whole logic inside the `if(m_target != null)` could be wrapped in a method.

Comment: I adapted the default script from the asset i used with chat gpt generated code and a bit of my own, so i got a bit messy i supposed. I will try your changes in my next school week and play around with it but everything made sense to me, so thank you for your time

Comment: Glad to know. Chat GPT is great but it will often write non-sense/out of date code. Be aware of that.

Comment: Did you end up trying the solution?